# Missing expression problem in SQL using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the number of employees by department and I wrote this script using Oracle but it always says that there is a missing expression

The columns used in my tables :

```
department :name (the name of the department) - 
depnum (the id of the department"primary key"), 
employee : empnum (the id of the employee) - 
depnum (the id of the department in which the employee in question is working "foreign key")
```

Query:

```
select 
    s.name 
from
    department s 
inner join 
    employee p on s.depnum = p.depnum 
group by 
    s.name 
having 
    count(p.empnum) = max(select count(p.empnum) 
                          from employee p, department s 
                          where s.depnum = p.depnum 
                          group by s.name) ;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. try to put some screenshots of required output and some sample input data.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: okay thank you , from this point onward i will be wary of it thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the number of employees by department, I would expect something like this:

```
select s.name, count(*) as num_employees
from department s inner join
     employe p
     on s.depnum = p.depnum 
group by s.name ;
```

If you want the department names with the maximum number of names, you can use a `having` clause:

```
select s.name, count(*) as num_employees
from department s inner join
     employe p
     on s.depnum = p.depnum 
group by s.name 
having count(*) = (select max(cnt)
                   from (select count(*) as cnt
                         from employee e2
                         group by e2.depnum
                        ) e2
                  );
```

The problem with your query is that you are attempting to take the `max()` of a subquery.  That syntax is not allowed -- and not necessary.

Comment: @AbHamidSajid . . . The very first sentence in your question is:  "I want to get the number of employees by department ".

Comment: your answer helped me a lot thank you so much i just need to take off the count(*) to get the exact result i need

Comment: yeah i'm truly sorry i should've motioned that in my question

Answer (score 0):

you sql statement is not correct that's why it thrown that error. I think you tried something like below

```
select s.name 
from department s 
inner join employe p on s.depnum=p.depnum 
group by s.name 
having count(p.empnum)=
select max(cnt) from 
( 
select count(p.empnum) as cnt
from employe p join department s 
on s.depnum=p.depnum 
group by s.name
 ) t;
```